# cname vs redirect

Tags: dns, openshift, cname

Ситуация следующая:

- Есть приложение на openshift'e которое доступно по урлу
  MYAPP.rhcloud.com
- Есть домен MYDOMAIN.com Хочу чтобы приложение было доступно по этому домену.

Текущее решение:
На опеншифте в инструкции написано создать CNAME запись у провайдера.
Но я не могу создать CNAME для корневой записи домена. MYDOMAIN.com CNAME MYAPP.rhcloud.com

Могу только SUBDOMAIN.MYDOMAIN.com CNAME MYAPP.rhcloud.com

Но я хочу чтобы мое приложение было доступно как www.MYDOMAIN.com так и MYDOMAIN.com
Для www.MYDOMAIN.com создать CNAME можно. А для MYDOMAIN.com пока вижу только купить самый дешевый хостинг и сделать редирект с MYDOMAIN.com на www.MYDOMAIN.com

Вопросы:
 1. Насколько это плохое решение?
 2. Может кто знает Днс где можно сделать CNAME на MYDOMAIN.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Может кто знает Днс где можно сделать CNAME на MYDOMAIN.com?

согласно [rfc1912](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1912.txt):

> A CNAME record is not allowed to coexist with any other data.
>   (вольный перевод: запись cname не может сосуществовать с любыми другими данными)

в случае делегированного вам доменного имени такими «сосуществующими данными» будет `soa`-запись, без которой само делегирование невозможно.

---

**но (бесплатный) выход есть**

вы можете воспользоваться каким-нибудь бесплатным «перенаправителем».

например: http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect

для этого сделайте *a*-запись для корня вашего домена, ведущую на *ip*-адрес «перенаправителя»:

```
@ in a 174.129.25.170
```

после этого все обращения по протоколу *http* к вашему домену `http://domen.vash` будут перенаправляться на `http://www.domen.vash`.

а для поддомена `www` уже настраивайте то, что требуется (`cname` и т.д. и т.п.).

---

демонстрация работоспособности упомянутого «перенаправителя»:

```
$ curl -I -H 'host: domen.vash' 174.129.25.170
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Fri, 25 Sep 2015 19:26:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.domen.vash/

$ curl -I -H 'host: blabla.bla' 174.129.25.170
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Fri, 25 Sep 2015 19:25:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.blabla.bla/
```